# Automating the process of restarting mathematica (and all open notebooks) after the operating system updates

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

The hassle of restarting Mathematica by hand after a required operating system restart makes it tempting to repeatedly delay operating system updates, which is a security risk.

Has anyone written mathematica code to automate this process?  (Ideally it would save all named and unnamed files to a temporary folder, store the values of all existing variables so that the files didn't have to be run again upon reload, and reload everything automatically.)

Comment: How is this a problem specific only to Mathematica? Do you experience frequent almost daily OS restarts? It is good practice to save your work frequently just in case Mathematica itself crashes unexpectedly or just its kernel. And to start from a fresh kernel since it may have unexpected values which are not current from your program.

Comment: The question is specific to mathematica because I expect there will be an automated solution specific to mathematica written in mathematica code.   Saving and reloading a dozen or more mathematica programs is a hassle, especially if you have to run lengthy calculations again to get them into their pre-restart state.   I don't know how to save a mathematica notebook in such a way that I can recover the pre-restart state (including all the variables in memory) without running again, but if you know a way please tell me.

Comment: You may find `DumpSave` has some of the functionality you want.